# Bluetooth headphones A2DP works but HSP/HFP does not on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, a2dp

I am able to connect my Bluetooth headphones. By default, the audio configuration is set to A2DP, and there is no sound. If I switch to HSP/HFP, I am able to hear. What could be the problem for A2DP?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you described with a *Beyerdynamic Lagoon ANC* headset, but with Linux Mint 20.3, which is based on Ubuntu 20.04.

To find the cause of my problem, I performed the following steps:

- Connected a different device (*Denon AVR-X2400H*) -> Worked
- Use Windows 10 (I have a dual boot) to verify hardware is working together -> Worked
- Updated kernel to the latest v5.13 one -> Not working
- Started a Linux Mint 20.3 live session from a USB pen drive with it's kernel 5.4.0-91-generic on a different PC -> Worked
- Did the same thing on the original PC. -> Worked
- Booted that 5.4.0-91-generic kernel from the Linux Mint 20.3 install on my PC (not a live session) -> Worked
- Booted back to the latest 5.4.0-113-generic session, which at that point I was sure to be the problem, but... -> Worked!!

## Solution:

I am a bit embarrassed to suggest my solution, which is simply to **turn up the volume at the headphone itself**. My headset has a volume control on the right side.

When **using A2DC**, the headset's volume is **NOT linked** to the volume in Linux Mint (in `cinnamon-settings sound`), i.e. I can have all sliders in Linux Mint set to 100% and still lower the volume at my headset itself to such a low level, that I hear nothing.
Using **HSP/HFP** the volume **is linked**. In that mode, using the volume control on my headset moves the slider in Linux Mint.

Apparently during my testing sessions I did that, or maybe in Windows the system volume is linked with the headset volume?!

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works for me on wf-1000xm5